# XSLT - regex replace character

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

I have a sample xsl like this,

```
<doc>
  <para>text . . .text</para>
  <para>text . . .text. . . . . .text</para>
</doc>
```

As you can see there are some patterns in the xml like `. . .`
what I need is replace space exist between dots with `*`. So output should be look like,

```
<doc>
  <para>text .*.*.text</para>
  <para>text .*.*.text.*.*.*.*.*.text</para>
</doc>
```

I've written following xslt for this,

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\.)(&#x0020;)(\.)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,regex-group(2),'*')"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

but it eliminate every other space and give me following result,

```
<doc>
  <para>text .*. .text</para>
  <para>text .*. .text.*. .*. .*.text</para>
</doc>
```

How can I modify my XSLT to get correct output..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\.)( )(\.)( \.)*">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ' ','*')"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

does the job. As LukStorms points out, that can be simplified to

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\.( \.)+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ' ','*')"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nice. :) And I think the regex can be simplified to `"\.( \.)+"`

Comment: @LukStorms, you are right, I have added your suggestion.

Comment: I assume those are ellipse dots, minimal three dots must. (\.)( )(\.)( \.)* to (\.)( )(\.)( \.)+ is ok. <para>text . .text</para> should not get * between.